# Нужна ли запятая перед тире? (4)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводное-слово, запятая-перед-тире

`Не знаю, но сейчас я работаю, потом ещë дела(,) — в общем, времени мало.`

Нужна ли запятая таки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна (по 7-му пункту): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103.

> Не знаю, но сейчас я работаю, потом ещë дела — в общем, времени мало.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Не знаю, но сейчас я работаю, потом ещë дела — **в общем, времени мало.***

**Пояснение**

Здесь **нет однородных членов**, но есть 4 предикативных основы. **Тире** обозначает **бессоюзную связь** между первой и второй частью предложения. Вторая часть обобщает первую, тире достаточно для обозначения таких отношений.